# gcp budget alert migration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alert, billing

I'm part of a google reseller. We have to change the billing sub account provided to our customer. In other word in the past we have assigned to him BILLING_A that he has used to link it to his project.
For internal reason we have to provide him another billing sub account but he have more then 100 projects and 20 budget alert.

I foound a script to read project and change billing id, but we have to do same thinks to Budget alert. There is a way to read them ad write on new billing sub account ?

Thx a lot

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please provide more details and context.

Comment: You have to write a script also to backup the billing alerts and then to restore them. Nothing out of the box

Answer (score 0):

sorry i try to be clearer.

Simplifying j need a script that download budget alert defined on a billing id and recreate them on another.

Thx

Comment: Your post is not an answer - delete it. Once you have written a script and you have a problem, post a question. Do not ask for someone to write a script for you.

Comment: yuo are right, i'm asking if some has find something similar in a public git to start with.

Answer (score 0):

i'm listied budget alert
gcloud billing budgets list --billing-account=0XXXXXX

but now how you can use this list to recreate them on new billing id?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: solved thx....with api download them and thne , changing json downloaded, a reload them one per time remobing two rows